# How can I check if an ArrayList contains a specific number of instances of a certain element?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm programming a Go Fish game for a project of mine, and I've been at this for a while. Currently I'm trying to check if the player/computer has a full book of a certain number. I've based the whole game off of arrays, and just need to check if the array contains four instances of a given element.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know the instanceof operator?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the specifics but this should get you started.

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < YOURARRAY.length; i++)
{
    if( //check to see if the element is the type youre counting)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
if(count == 4)
{
    //there are 4 instances
}
```